# Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' - not found when using PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit, php-ziparchive

I have refactored some PHP code and putting it through a series of PHPUnit classes.

I get the above Fatal Error when running PHPUnit (3.7.28) on it (through console).

PHP version is 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.4 (cli).

I know the Zip class is working and available as it works when running the code normally (also via console)

Thoughts / ideas appreciated.

Thanks!

```
<?php

namespace phpUnit\Test;

Class MyTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
Public Function setUp()
    {
    $this->zip = new ZipArchive();
    }
}
```

Comment: This [looks like a module](http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php) that needs enabling. Maybe PHPUnit is using a different version of PHP?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I have found the php.ini file and examined - zip.so is not contained within it. I have requested the server admins to correct this and we'll see.

Comment: Besides your code above will never work. You'd have to write ``$this->zip = new \ZipArchive()`` unless this class is defined within the namespace ``phpUnit\Test``.

Answer (score 1):

Inside a namespace, you have to reference classes (other than functions) with their fully qualified class name or import them first:

```
$this->zip = new \ZipArchive();
```

or

```
namespace phpUnit\Test;
use ZipArchive;
```

Your "normal" code is probably not using namespaces if it works there.

Comment: From the discussion above with l-x we'd established that ZipArchive() was not fully qualified using the \ symbol,